# Test for Value of Empty Dropdown in AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an AppsScript in place to move a row from one sheet to another based on the value in a dropdown, and it works virtually perfectly.

However, I want for it to be where if the user deletes the selection in the dropdown, it goes to a specific sheet, how would I achieve this?

I have tried using null in hoping that value would work as detecting an empty dropdown:

`const srcArray = [null,'No Update','In Progress','Completed'];`

`const destArray = ['New','New','New','COMPLETED'];`

But in the above code the null value doesn't work, but all other ones do perfectly fine.

The srcArray is the option from the dropdown (except for null, of course), and the destArray is the respective sheet it moves the row to (e.g. No Update moves to New, while Completed moves to COMPLETED).

Ideally I want to replace that null value with something that denotes when the dropdown is empty from pressing delete on it. Is there a value I can replace null with to achieve this? Or perhaps another (hopefully straightforward) method for that?

Full Code:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  let r = e.range;

  if (r.columnStart != 5 || r.rowStart == 1 || r.rowStart == 2 || r.rowStart == 3 || r.rowStart == 4 || r.rowStart == 5 || e.value == null) return;

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  const srcArray = [null,'No Update','In Progress','Completed'];
  const destArray = ['New','New','New','COMPLETED'];

  let src = sheet.getActiveSheet();
  let dest = sheet.getSheetByName(destArray[srcArray.indexOf(e.value)]);

  if (dest.getName() == src.getName()) return;

  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,9).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,9));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: Validation does not allow empty cells

Comment: @Cooper ah, so dumb question, but that means there's no type of workaround for that? People would just have to select from the dropdown and not delete selection?

Comment: This is one of those features that have adapted to a variety of different uses over the years.  Perhaps you can make a case for them to add your needs into a feature request.  In the beginning one could select a range bigger than needed and it would automatically resize to the number of non empty cells thus making it possible to be easily updated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the user deletes the selection in the dropdown` and `Ideally I want to replace that null value with something that denotes when the dropdown is empty from pressing delete on it. Is there a value I can replace null with to achieve this?`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `but that means there's no type of workaround for that?` Rather than rely on there being a non-existent "blank" dropdown, create a dropdown that suggests/implies a "blank" (such as "Not Assigned"?).